# Read images from folder to tensors in torch and run a binary classifier

Tags: python, pytorch, classification

I would like to load images from a local directory in Torch in order to train a binary classifier. My directory looks as follows:

```
-data
   - class_1_folder
   - class_2_folder
```

My folders `class_1` and `class_2` contain the .jpg images for each class. My images do have various sizes (mostly rectangular shapes though). I am using the following code to read my files:

```
import os
import pdb
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.transforms.functional import to_pil_image

PATH = "data/"

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                            transforms.RandomCrop(224),
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224,0.225])])

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(PATH, transform=transform)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=356, shuffle=True)
images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
tensor_image = images[1]
img = to_pil_image(inv_normalize(tensor_image))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

When I check these results with `imshow`, it seems that the `imshow` portrays a `grid` with the image nine times (`3X3`). How to avoid that? Is there a way also to revert the transformations easily before the `imshow`?

I am trying to do something to `invert` the `normalization` like the following:

```
inv_normalize = transforms.Normalize(
                            mean=[-0.485/0.229, -0.456/0.224, -0.406/0.255],
                            std=[1/0.229, 1/0.224, 1/0.255]
)
```

However, the results are still a bit weird! Isn't that a correct `invert` transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_pil_image`

```
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.transforms.functional import to_pil_image

tr = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                            transforms.RandomCrop(224),
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224,0.225])])
img = Image.open("/content/cat-2083492__340.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)

img = tr(img)
plt.figure()
print(img.shape, type(img))
img = img*(torch.tensor([0.229, 0.224,0.225])).reshape(3, 1, 1) + torch.tensor([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]).reshape(3, 1, 1)
img = to_pil_image(img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

**Note** `to_pil_image` will only change the order of dimensions
https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage

Comment: Ok now it seems that the grid is removed with to_pil_image. However, still, the images seem weird and I guess I need to perform the inverse normalization to portray it, properly! Btw, why I got the issue with the grid? Do you have any clue?

Comment: yes, `to_pil_image`, as I said in my answer only change the order of dimensions, it does not scale values, you have to scale them manually. **Update** because you are reshaping the tensor in a wrong way, you should have used `permute`, not `view`

Comment: I am trying to perform an invert_normalization (as the one you could find in my updated question) but it does not work quite well. I got some weird artifacts in the result.

Comment: You are doing it also wrong), I will update my answer with full example

Comment: Glad to help. Please note that the values are in the range of [0, 1]. 
So if you want to save them as an image, don't forget to multiply them by 255 and convert them to uint8